# Entry point hardware for profitable mining

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, solo-mining

A) Which hardware
B) Which GH/s level

will be profitable for

1) Pool mining
2) Solo mining

Bitcoins as of February 2014?

Links to sources where information can be checked over time will be great, beyond the simple answer to the questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to experience the thrill of mining?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/how-to-experience-the-thrill-of-mining)

Comment: Not duplicate because this one focus on profitability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is what kind of coin are you going to mine. If you are going to mine Bitcoin (SHA256) you will need special hardware (ASIC 28nm min) for it to be profitable. [Here](https://www.kncminer.com/) you have an excellent seller, I bought my mining equipment from them, but now they sold out their next generation devices. If you want to mine this coins you will have to risk buying ahead of time, I mean you will have to buy a device that is in development and wait like 6 months for the hardware to arrive, so you will need [this calculator](http://btcinvest.net/en/bitcoin-mining-profit-calculator.php?diff=2621404453&dcosts=500&diff_mincrease=30&blpbtc=25&dhsmhs=860&diff_mincreasedecrease=3&btcusd=847.69&dpowcon=30&btcusd_mincrease=1&pcost=0.25&calcweeks=32&dleadtime=0&action=calc) to make a preview of what your profits will be. Actually there are many other sellers (Butterfly Labs -which I do not recommend-, Cointerra, make your own search in google, but KNC for me is the most trusted one). [Here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) you have a comparison of mining devices for Bitcoin.

If you plan to mine Litecoin (Scrypt) you will be able to do that with GPUs, you have a mining hardware comparison [here](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison).

You will first need to decide which coin are you going to mine and what kind of ecryption are you going to be solving (SHA256, Scrypt). You will need to consider what kind of risk you want to take, for instance, if you mine Bitcoins you know it is the safest bet with an actual price of 803$ and having reached 1150$ per coin it is cryptocoin that is being accepted in stores right now therefore it has a possible great future. On the other hand, mining this coin has become difficult and a considerable investment and risk is needed to aquire the hardware needed.

On the other hand, if you choose a coin which has recently started, it will be easier to mine those coins, but it won't be profitable (if you think that coin could gain value in the future then it may end being profitable, who knows).

Finally it is up to you to read and choose where you want to enter and what amount of money you want to risk.

Comment: Thanks. I referred to Bitcoin. Edited. BTW, your answer covers A) but not B), and does not clarify if it covers 1) or 2) above.

Comment: Bitcoin will not be profitable in solo mining unless you get really lucky which I doubt, or you have a super mega ASIC rig. Pool mining is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. What about GH/s ?

Comment: KNC's new machines have 3TH/s minimum and they are supposed to arrive around 2Q this year. It all depends on how fast you are going to have your machine, 280GH/s is mining 0.06BTC per day right now, which are 48$/day. Use the link to the calculator I posted to see what you can expect and what GH/s or TH/s you will need to make your profit.

Answer (score 0):

Buy Antminer S1s 200 GH for 1.45 BTC Ships Saturday.  Just buy a CX750 for another 90 bucks and you're set to Mine.  Genesis Block Shows Net Gain of $1100 or 1.19 BTC by August.  http://thegenesisblock.com/mining/a/31ee55a871

https://bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=00020140107162747992Ce5uBuxW06D6

Everything else I have found is either:

A) overpriced
B) delayed

or more likely

C) both

Comment: 200GH for 1.45BTC??? Expected coins to mine with that GH are 2.04 minus electricity costs. Just 0.59BTC of profit???? Better go to an exchange and invest your money buying the coins directly in the exchange.